# Running Chromium OS on Windows using Qemu

Tags: windows, qemu, chromium-os

I'm trying to boot a build of Chromium OS on a Windows 7 machine using Qemu and I'm running into some issues. I've built the OS as per the instructions on the website and have the output file (`chromiumos_qemu_image.bin`) in the same directory as Qemu. I modified the batch file for running Linux to run the chromiumos as follows:

```
REM Start qemu on windows.
@ECHO OFF

REM SDL_VIDEODRIVER=directx is faster than windib. But keyboard cannot work well.
SET SDL_VIDEODRIVER=windib

REM SDL_AUDIODRIVER=waveout or dsound can be used. Only if QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=sdl.
SET SDL_AUDIODRIVER=dsound

REM QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=dsound or fmod or sdl or none can be used. See qemu -audio-help.
SET QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=dsound

REM QEMU_AUDIO_LOG_TO_MONITOR=1 displays log messages in QEMU monitor.
SET QEMU_AUDIO_LOG_TO_MONITOR=0

REM PCI-based PC(default): -M pc 
REM ISA-based PC         : -M isapc
REM -M isapc is added for NE2000 ISA card.

qemu.exe -L . -m 128 -hda chromiumos_qemu_image.bin -soundhw sb16,es1370 -localtime -M pc
```

When I run this a GUI pops up that seems to be attempting to run the OS but it just stays black. I've enabled intel-vt on my machine but beyond that I'm not really sure what else to do.